# Textinputlayout space between hint and edittext

Tags: android, kotlin, android-textinputlayout

Is there some way to add space between hint and edittext? My edittext is multiline and when theres to much text and lines hint can overlap edittext.

[image]

I want additional spacing between hint and edittext, probably 4dp

Thank you in advance for your cooperation

Comment: The hint of textinputlayout is supposed to switch position once you start typing in the edit text. So it is not supposed to overlap with the edittext. Can you please include relevant code in your question so that it becomes easier to identify the issue?

Comment: I agree with @ganjaam. code is needed